# "I can help", "I'm of help", "Be of Use"

Tags: prepositions, verbs

I would like to ask you to answer the difference between "I can help" and "I'm help of". Besides, explain the meaning of this idiom: "be of"

> "I'm of help"
>
> "I can help"
>
> "I can be of use"

Comment: Have you looked up definitions of these phrases?  Have you noticed that two of these phrases are common, and one is rare?  What are you confused about?

Comment: Yes,I want to know this( be of help/sub+ verb+ of)     how to use.

Comment: Are you aware of the usage of **of** in these phrases - *man of value, work of fiction* etc? What **of** does to those phrases is that the word following **of** becomes the quality of the word coming before **of**. In your sentence - **I'm of help** - that **of** is acting like the same way. **I am (the person) of help**. **to help** is my quality. **I'm helpful**.

Comment: As an American native speaker: I've only heard "of help"/"of use" used with "*be*". I think "I can *be of help* to you." is correct, but "I am of help to you" sounds very odd.

Comment: _man of my word_ is a related expression that might be easier to search for. I would say this isn't really a common speech pattern in modern English and most people would have difficulty explaining it. Try replacing _of use_  with the adjective _useful_ and _of help_ with _helpful_.

Comment: @apsillers "was I of any use?" yields surprisingly few results on Google, but I'm pretty sure it's a correct phrase, if a bit overtly polite.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the last part - it generally means "to provide help/use/whatever", but you'll be hard-pressed to find it used this way in modern English outside of those two phrases (to be of help / to be of use). It's best to just consider those two full idioms and not try to dissect them.

As for the meanings, they're mostly the same. "Can I be of any help/use?" is somewhat more polite (maybe even *too* polite in some contexts) when you're offering help than a stern "Can I help?", but both are fine in my book.

As for the difference between "being of help/helping" and "being of use" - again, they're mostly interchangeable. Personally, I consider "being of help" to be more polite and focused on the people involved, and "being of use" as kind of depersonalizing yourself (in general, people are helpful, and objects/tools are useful), but that's just a subtlety.